# How to make a pdf of a specific part of a html file in django

Tags: python, django, xhtml2pdf

I want to generate pdf from html in django using xhtml2pdf. But xhtml2pdf seems to make a PDF of full HTML template. What I want to say is that suppose I have a side menu, a header, a footer and a table of some contents in my html file. Now, I want to only generate pdf of that table from the html file. How can I do that using xhtml2pdf ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate your template files for different part of the page.  For example, you may have a base html that contains the common templates, and you will also have your `table.html` that contains the data you want to convert to pdf.

You can use `include` built-in templatetag to use it in another template: See docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include).  You can aslo check `extends` templatetag which is very handy [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#extends).

Something like this:

```
# base.html
{% include 'table.html' %}

# views.py
def render_to_pdf(request):
    template_path = 'table.html'  # Here is the template you want to convert
    context = {'myvar': 'this is your template context'}

    # Create a Django response object, and specify content_type as pdf
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="report.pdf"'

    # find the template and render it.
    template = get_template(template_path)
    html = template.render(Context(context))

    # create a pdf
    pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(
      html, dest=response, link_callback=link_callback)
    # if error then show some funy view
    if pisaStatus.err:
      return HttpResponse('We had some errors <pre>' + html + '</pre>')
    return response
```

You can see the pdf creation in xhtml2pdf docs [here](http://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-xhtml2pdf-in-django)